# Cannot display friends list facebook on my Android App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to make an Android application which can display my friends list. I have tried to do according to this tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/show-friends
Up to now, I can sign in my Facebook via my own Android app but I am stuck in the step that how to display my friends list on list view
Please kindly help me, I need the reason why it cannot display like the above tutorial.
Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're apparently using the Graph API v2.0, then this is by design only showing the friends who also use your app.

See [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-use-m?rq=1)